# Decreasing debounce time of mouse

Tags: mouse, time, mouse-click, mouse-buttons

I bought new mouse "Razer deathadder essential". This mouse has a double click prevention, that mean debounce time is big but I need debounce time set to minimum. How could I do that? I know such a program called "Auto Hotkey" but I don't know how to use.

Comment: It sounds like Razer mice have issues with (possibly) low-quality buttons, and after a while their [contact bounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce) becomes problematic... It's looks like a firmware update has increase the debounce time to mitigate this, but this is not something you can alter with software on your computer. [How fast can you click?](https://clickspeedtest.com/) Can you try with this mouse, and another mouse? (for reference, I think that around 5 CPS is acceptable for double clicking, though may not be acceptable for games / other uses).

Comment: With bloody I could do 20 cps, with Razer only 10 cps

Comment: I watched video of one guy who has the same mouse and he can double click

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:no. The minimum debounce time is coded within the firmware of the mouse. Only the manufacturer has the source-code and the ability to reduce that time. Auto Hotkey is used to "increase" the debounce time for a mouse whose double-click prevention has failed.
Suppose, you used AutoHotKey to reduce the debounce-time, then when those clicks will pass through the firmware of the mouse, it will surely trigger the double click prevention and only one click will be registered.